# Creating a property as a list or array with properties

Tags: vb.net, properties, visual-studio-2015, .net-4.6

I would like to create a array or list property with theses results:

```
team(1).name = "Falcons"
team(1).totalPoints = 167
team(2).name = "Jets"
team(2).totalPoints = 121
```

and so on....

I know how to make properties, but not as an array or list.  Thanks.

Comment: There is no such thing as "sub properties".  Write a class with those properties and store it in an array of `List(Of T)`

Comment: ^^ array **or** `List(Of T)`

Comment: what would you call it, sorry for my ignorance

Comment: A Class (such as NFLTeam) would keep multiple bits of data about one thing together (such as {Name, Wins, TotalPoints, PointsAgainst, Players(),  OffensiveRank, DefensiveRank, Division etc etc etc}

Comment: Thanks @plutonix for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no sub-properties in .net, but you can achieve your target by creating a List of objects of a class that having properties. try the following:

```
Public Class Team
    Private _Name As String
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _Name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Name = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _TotalPoints As Integer
    Public Property TotalPoints() As Integer
        Get
            Return _TotalPoints
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _TotalPoints = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Then you can create a list of objects of the class `Team` as follows:

```
 Dim TeamList As New List(Of Team)
 TeamList.Add(New Team() With {.Name = "Falcons", .TotalPoints = 167})
 TeamList.Add(New Team() With {.Name = "Jets", .TotalPoints = 121})
```

So that ;

```
TeamList(0).Name         Gives  "Falcons"
TeamList(0).TotalPoints  Gives   167
TeamList(1).Name         Gives   "Jets"
TeamList(1).TotalPoints  Gives   121
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!